PrimeNG sidebar clears primeng messages. Why?
In my app.component.html I have
<div class="main">
    <button type="button" (click)="onShowNotificationSideBar()" label="Show"></button>  
    <p-sidebar [(visible)]="notificationSideBarVisible" position="right" [style]="{width:'50em'}">
        <button type="button" pButton pRipple (click)="showSuccess()" label="S" class="p-button-success"></button>        
        <button type="button" pButton pRipple (click)="showWarn()" label="W" class="p-button-warning"></button>
        <button type="button" pButton pRipple (click)="showError()" label="E" class="p-button-danger"></button>
        <h3>Messages</h3>
        <h5>{{messages}}</h5>
        <p-messages [(value)]="messages" [enableService]="false" ></p-messages>
    </p-sidebar>
    <p-toast position="center"></p-toast>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

in app.component.ts I have
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Message, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [MessageService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'WECO';
  notificationSideBarVisible = false;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
    messageService.messageObserver.subscribe((m:Message | Message[])=>{
      if (!Array.isArray(m)){
        this.messages.push(m)
      }
      this.messages = [...this.messages];
    });
  }

  onShowNotificationSideBar(){
    this.notificationSideBarVisible=true;
  }

  count=0;

  messages : Message[] = [
    // { severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Message Content' },
    // { severity: 'info', summary: 'Info', detail: 'Message Content' },
    // { severity: 'warn', summary: 'Warning', detail: 'Message Content' },
    // { severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Message Content' }
  ];

  longSentence = 'Let’s end all this nonsense about how long sentences = run-on sentences. You can have a six-word run-on sentence (“I went shopping I ate donuts.”), while most of the sentences below are much, much longer than that and are not run-ons';//'And let’s end all this nonsense about how long sentences = run-on sentences. You can have a six-word run-on sentence (“I went shopping I ate donuts.”), while most of the sentences below are much, much longer than that and are not run-ons (except for a few examples like Jose Saramago).  But whether the sentence is grammatically correct isn’t nearly as important as whether the sentence is fun or beautiful.'

  showWarn(){
    let detail='User Deleted a Weco Rule';
    if (this.count++%5===0)
      detail = this.longSentence;
    this.messageService.add({severity:'warn', summary:'User Action', detail: detail});
  }

  showSuccess(){
    let detail = 'Weco Rule 123 Saved';
    if (this.count++%5===0)
      detail = this.longSentence;
    this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Service Call', detail:detail});
  }

  showError(){
    let detail = 'api-call:get-factories returned 404';
    if (this.count++%5===0)
      detail = this.longSentence;
    this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Service Call', detail:detail});
  }
}

If I open side bar and add some messages in it they appear, but when I close and reopen they are gone.
Even though I can see that messages variable still has them. Why?

P.S.
If I then add some more messages I only see the new ones.

The sidebar menu has a component called p-messages, if you check the element, you will note that the p-sidebar contents gets destroyed when you close.
When you reopen the sidebar, the data stays the same, but the messages are destroyed.
I think the p-messages component will only show the array references are getting changed, this might be due to the *ngFor inside the component with a trackBy, so we need to reset each array elements reference in memory, so that we trick p-messages into thinking that there are new messages in the list, for this we can use object destructuring! I will do this when the sidebar is opened (onShowNotificationSideBar)
onShowNotificationSideBar() {
    this.notificationSideBarVisible = true;
    this.messages = [...this.messages.map(x => ({...x}))]; // <- creates new references for the array and its contents!
}

full code
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Message, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './sidebar-basic-demo.html',
  providers: [MessageService],
})
export class SidebarBasicDemo {
  title = 'WECO';
  notificationSideBarVisible = false;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
    messageService.messageObserver.subscribe((m: Message | Message[]) => {
      if (!Array.isArray(m)) {
        this.messages.push(m);
      }
      this.messages = [...this.messages];
    });
  }

  onShowNotificationSideBar() {
    this.notificationSideBarVisible = true;
    this.messages = [...this.messages.map(x => ({...x}))];
  }

  count = 0;

  messages: Message[] = [
    // { severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Message Content' },
    // { severity: 'info', summary: 'Info', detail: 'Message Content' },
    // { severity: 'warn', summary: 'Warning', detail: 'Message Content' },
    // { severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Message Content' }
  ];

  longSentence =
    'Let’s end all this nonsense about how long sentences = run-on sentences. You can have a six-word run-on sentence (“I went shopping I ate donuts.”), while most of the sentences below are much, much longer than that and are not run-ons'; //'And let’s end all this nonsense about how long sentences = run-on sentences. You can have a six-word run-on sentence (“I went shopping I ate donuts.”), while most of the sentences below are much, much longer than that and are not run-ons (except for a few examples like Jose Saramago).  But whether the sentence is grammatically correct isn’t nearly as important as whether the sentence is fun or beautiful.'

  showWarn() {
    let detail = 'User Deleted a Weco Rule';
    if (this.count++ % 5 === 0) detail = this.longSentence;
    this.messageService.add({
      severity: 'warn',
      summary: 'User Action',
      detail: detail,
    });
  }

  showSuccess() {
    let detail = 'Weco Rule 123 Saved';
    if (this.count++ % 5 === 0) detail = this.longSentence;
    this.messageService.add({
      severity: 'success',
      summary: 'Service Call',
      detail: detail,
    });
  }

  showError() {
    let detail = 'api-call:get-factories returned 404';
    if (this.count++ % 5 === 0) detail = this.longSentence;
    this.messageService.add({
      severity: 'error',
      summary: 'Service Call',
      detail: detail,
    });
  }
}

html
<div class="main">
  <button type="button" (click)="onShowNotificationSideBar()" label="Show">
    show sidebar
  </button>
  <p-sidebar
    [(visible)]="notificationSideBarVisible"
    position="right"
    [style]="{width:'50em'}"
  >
    <button
      type="button"
      pButton
      pRipple
      (click)="showSuccess()"
      label="S"
      class="p-button-success"
    >
      success
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      pButton
      pRipple
      (click)="showWarn()"
      label="W"
      class="p-button-warning"
    >
      warn
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      pButton
      pRipple
      (click)="showError()"
      label="E"
      class="p-button-danger"
    >
      error
    </button>
    <h3>Messages</h3>
    <h5>{{messages}}</h5>
    <p-messages [(value)]="messages" [enableService]="false"></p-messages>
  </p-sidebar>
  <p-toast position="center"></p-toast>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you @Narin that does fix the problem, but I still would like to  know why it happened. Is this for some reason intended behavior by primeng? Or a bug?

@ILIABROUDNO The component got created and destroyed,  the change detection is set to OnPush in the sourceCode so we need to update the references of the elements, inorder for the change detection to run inside p-messages, this is my theory
